# How can I fix lightdm login black border?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xubuntu, lightdm, login-screen

There is a black border around my login screen every time I boot up. I have a second monitor connected and noticed that the background of the first monitor shrinks so that it matches the background of the second monitor. There is a black border that fills the empty area after shrink.

I tried changing login screen settings using ubuntu tweak, LightDM GTK+ Greeter:settings, and manually editing the lightDM conf files. None of these changed the background.

I am using NVIDIA binary driver - version 352.63 from Software & Updates on xubuntu. I have also tried using Nouveau driver but caused resolution to default to 800x600.

lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf:

```
[greeter]
theme-name = Greybird
icon-theme-name = elementary-xfce-dark
font-name = Droid Sans 10
xft-antialias = true
xft-dpi = 96
xft-hintstyle = slight
xft-rgba = rgb
show-indicators = power;~session;~language;~a11y;~power;
show-clock = true
clock-format = %d %b, %H:%M
keyboard = onboard
default-user-image = #xfce-internet
#background = /usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/solitude.jpg
background=#ffffff
```

folder contents:

```
lightdm
----lightdm.conf.d
--------10-xubuntu.conf
----lightdm-gtk.greeter.conf
----lightdm.conf
----users.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also been unable to change the image to make it fill the login screen. However, you can change it to your hexadecimal background color of choice. This will fix the black border.

In terminal, use your favorite text editor to open:

```
sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
```

Then do the following:

```
# background=/lib/plymouth/themes/xubuntu-logo/wallpaper.png
background=#709078
```

It is a good idea to comment out what was there originally in case you want to go back. I would go to [a site like this one](http://www.colorcombos.com/333333-hex-color) to pick out the color you prefer.

Comment: I did exactly as instructed and now I have a shrunk wallpapaer with the border being `#709078` color. I'll edit my question with the conf.

Comment: That is strange. I tested exactly as your file is above and did not have that issue. In the past I have fixed a similar issue by doing what was in my answer. However, this was on Fedora Xfce, and I have ATI graphics. I'm sorry it didn't work out. Maybe a reboot would do the trick?

Comment: Just tried reboot with no luck. I've spent many hours looking for a solution and I've come to realize this is either a bug or I did something wrong somewhere. This is a relatively new install so I'm considering to just reinstall as a last case. I'm going to try out other login managers later. I'm sure  your answer will help someone else out :)

Comment: Best of luck! :)